# mod_rewrite URL part after # hash

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL that looks like this

```
mysite.com/#!/~/category/id=2925536&offset=0&sort=priceAsc
```

how can I change it to something like this?

```
mysite.com/#category/2925536/0/priceAsc
```

Comment: I need it to look something like mysite.com/#category/2925536/0/priceAsc

Answer (score 2):

Fragment identifiers (a hash tag is something used to identify a search term on Twitter, not part of a URI) are handled client side and are never passed to the server. They therefore cannot be read with mod_rewrite. You would need to use something that runs client side (e.g. JavaScript) to handle that.

You may wish to consider [not using the hashbang URI technique](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs), even Twitter is abandoning it.

Comment: it's ECWID. everything loads with javascript. the url is used for sharing etc.